# MVC application under NGNIX rule to run application with virtual directory URL

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have MVC 5 application which is running on IIS on this URL http://localhost:8080. I want to get it run by appending some text in the url like http://localhost:8080/app. To achieve this I have done below things.

1. Setup Nginx server to redirect url for /app

   ```
   server   {
                  listen       8080;
                  server_name  localhost;
                  location /app
                  {
                  proxy_pass   http://localhost:8084/;
                  } 
        }
   ```
2. Created directory structure on server like this C:\intepub\Test\app
3. Created application under Test folder on IIS like below.

   IIS 
   --Test (Virtual Directory)
   -- app (as web application under Test) --This is in asp.net MVC5

After doing all this steps when I run the application using url http://localhost:8080/app it didn't worked and getting below exception:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
> removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Comment: Why would you need nginx in 1)? Then why a virtual directory and an IIS application under it? You can do many things, but without a clear reason you are just moving on the wrong direction. To fulfill your original requirement, just host the MVC web app as an IIS application called `app` under that web site at port 8080.

Comment: Your Test folder is Virtual Directory, if you want to access mvc content through http://localhost:8080/app, you should create app under root directory, this link about how to publish asp.net mvc to iis should help you: [https://www.compilemode.com/2021/04/how-to-host-asp-net-mvc-web-app-on-local-iis.html](https://www.compilemode.com/2021/04/how-to-host-asp-net-mvc-web-app-on-local-iis.html).

Comment: @LexLi Thank for your reply. Did you mean to host MVC application under the root folder of IIS ? If yes how can I fullfill my requirement to run application localhost:8080/app ? I can remove Nginx but to get /app work in URL what are options I have to do and how?